# Apache Hudi deltastreamer throwing Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException' no main parameter was defined

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, apache-hudi

Version Apache Hudi 0.6.1,Spark 2.4.6

Below is the standard spark-submit command for Hudi deltastreamer, where it is throwing as no main parameter is defined. I could see all the properties parameters are given.  Appreciate any help on this error.

```
[hadoop@ip-00-00-00-00 target]$ spark-submit   --class org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer 'ls /mnt/hudi/packaging/hudi-utilities-bundle/target/hudi-utilities-bundle_2.11-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' --master yarn --deploy-mode client --storage-type COPY_ON_WRITE --source-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.sources.JsonKafkaSource --source-ordering-field ts --target-base-path /user/hive/warehouse/stock_ticks_cow  --target-table stock_ticks_cow --props /var/demo/config/kafka-source.properties --schemaprovider-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.schema.FilebasedSchemaProvider
20/09/08 05:14:46 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '--master' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class
        at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.initMainParameterValue(JCommander.java:936)
        at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:752)
        at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:340)
        at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:319)
        at org.apache.hudi.com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:240)
        at org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer.getConfig(HoodieDeltaStreamer.java:445)
        at org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer.main(HoodieDeltaStreamer.java:454)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/09/08 05:14:46 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/09/08 05:14:46 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-3ad6af85-94be-4117-a479-53423a91fd75
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the way the parms of spark-submit and class is conflicting, so I followed the order as given below and it worked

```
spark-submit \
--jars "/mnt/hudi/packaging/hudi-utilities-bundle/target/hudi-utilities-bundle_2.11-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" \
--deploy-mode "client" \
--class "org.apache.hudi.utilities.deltastreamer.HoodieDeltaStreamer" \
/mnt/hudi/packaging/hudi-utilities-bundle/target/hudi-utilities-bundle_2.11-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
--props /var/demo/config/kafka-source.properties \
--table-type COPY_ON_WRITE \
--source-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.sources.JsonKafkaSource \
--source-ordering-field ts \
--target-base-path /user/hive/warehouse/stock_ticks_cow \
--target-table stock_ticks_cow \
--schemaprovider-class org.apache.hudi.utilities.schema.FilebasedSchemaProvider
```